# intercept url doesn't work with spring security angular

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security

I'am trying to manage users authentication, my config is:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated() and hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
                  <security:intercept-url pattern="/public/**" access="isAuthenticated() and hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
```

my problem is only admin can log in but others i get this message "Etat HTTP 403 - Access is denied" any solution for this problem ?

Comment: The order in which security rules are specified is the order in which they are consulted... Hence a `/**` should *always* be last and not first.

Comment: thank you for your answer ,i changed the order but user can't accede to views under folder "public"

Comment: Are they logged in? You have currently protected everything, also your rule is a bit redundant, `hasRole` implies that someone is `authenticated` else he doesn't have the rule.

Comment: they aren't logged in yet, i'm trying to filter redirection of users

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the first rule was too much restrictive and in all url Spring security check if the user has ROLE_ADMIN. Now I don't know what are the your security requirements but consider that the first rule that stop the evaluation in your case the first stop the filtring of the your request and denay the call of other user.

you can try in this way:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/public/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
```

in this case you say that the public url have as security requirements that the user has USER Role, and if this requirements are not true you evaluate if is a ADMIN, the second rule.

If you note I delete the isAuthenticated(), in this case I check only the role of the logged user.

I hope that this can help you

Comment: i changed my code but it doesn't work , i think that it is caused by angularjs , since angularjs work with '#' but i don't know how to resolve it

Comment: it is stange I use Angular with spring Security and for me all work correctly.

Comment: so please tell me if "public" should be the folder of my views or should be the path used in angular services

Comment: public should be used in the path but I search in internet and I consider that you could read this ahttps://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/.      I don'tn know all detail of the your application but I used Thymeleaf and angular i a my open source project and if you want can read the code for ispiration. https://github.com/mrFlick72/socialDocumentLibrary